# How to Add small logo or image to email body in Apple mail?

Tags: macos, plugins, applescript, xcode4.5, apple-mail

I am new to developing plugins for Apple Mail for Mac OS X,

So I don't know how can I add a small logo or image to email content (body) before any email address,

Means we also need to detect the email address in email body, and than add logo next to every email.
like this one 
[image]

how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to write a service in Automator (e.g. using Ruby or Python)?